# Getting (ping) delay time to microseconds (less than 1 millisecond) in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, delay, ping

I want to measure the amount of delay inside a network using asp.net core, but since the delay is between 0 and 1 millisecond (eg 0.263 milliseconds), it returns 0.

Is there a way to get the delay in asp.net core, in microseconds?

```
public void OnGet()
{
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("localhost");

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        TempData["RoundTrip time"]= "RoundTrip time: "+ reply.RoundtripTime;
    }
}
```

The idea I have is a terrible idea in coding that works, but I don't want to do it in an unprincipled way:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    DateTime t1;
    DateTime t2;

    Ping pingSender = new Ping();

    t1 = DateTime.Now;
    PingReply reply = pingSender.Send("localhost");            
    t2 = DateTime.Now;

    long b = (long)t2.Subtract(t1).TotalMilliseconds;
    long b2 = (long)t2.Subtract(t1).TotalMicroseconds;
    long b3 = (long)t2.Subtract(t1).TotalNanoseconds;

    TempData["t"] = b;
    TempData["t2"] = b2;
    TempData["t3"] = b3;
}
```

Comment: Not using .Net `Ping` where [`PingReply.RoundTripTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply.roundtriptime?view=net-7.0#system-net-networkinformation-pingreply-roundtriptime) is in milliseconds only.  There are any number of high-resolution Ping utilities you could invoke, redirecting and parsing it's stdout output, or you could write your own ping client class using performance counters for high resolution timing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "hrPing-high percision ping utility" http://www.cfos.de/en/ping/ping.htm#howto
The standard output is like
[image]

And you can try the following code

```
            string RoundTripTime=string.Empty;
            var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "E:\\hrping.exe",
                    Arguments = "localhost -n 1",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains("time="))
                {
                    RoundTripTime = line.Split(new string[] { "time=" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
                }
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine(RoundTripTime);
```

output
[image]

Comment: tnk, its work, but I do not have access to the server hard drive.